# pre-commit to call executable multiple times with every single file changed

Tags: git, terraform, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I am trying to lint some terraform files in my Git repo and would like to run `terraform fmt --write-true <for every modified file>`.

Is there a way to configure pre-commit hooks to call the executable on every changed file, rather than calling it once with the list of files?

The constraint is that `terraform fmt` requires a single filename or the entire directory.

The documentation only states that the changed files are passed as a hook and I would like to avoid writing another script to handle the args one by one.

Comment: Any reason you only want to run it against changed files instead of just everything recursively?

Comment: Yeah because we have lots of files and do not want to change everything right now.

Comment: So finally, I just formatted the entire repo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe specifying `xargs -n 1 terraform fmt --write-true` as the hook command would work for this case. The `-n` argument to `xargs` specifies the maximum number of arguments per invocation.